# What are the advantages / disadvantages of using guest access AWS identity pool for public API endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have some public REST endpoints hosted on AWS using API Gateway. They are public endpoints that I am happy for any visitor to the website to access. I have been recommended as a security precaution to use Amplify and an AWS Identity pool with guest access enabled, to gain creds and sign requests. Then the API gateway can check the signatures of the requests. The one advantage I am aware of is that this is similar to using an API key, but you don't need to hard code the API key into the web application.

However I'm not sure I understand what the other advantages are of this method. Whilst I don't have an API key publicly visible in the web app code, anyone is still able to gain access via the guest access cognito pool are they not? Or does the AWS cognito identity pool have some fancy checks going on in the background that I am unaware of?

Thank you for your help!